# MySQL doesn't use index as expected

Tags: mysql, indexing, subquery

`EXPLAIN` on this query

```
select v.type,sum(c.rank)
from
  (select distinct power,color,type from vehicle) v
  join configuration c using (power,color)
group by v.type
```

gives

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type |     table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys |     key     | key_len |                   ref                   |  rows   | filtered |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | configuration | NULL       | ALL   | veh           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                    |   76658 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 6       | configuration.power,configuration.color |      65 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  2 | DERIVED     | vehicle       | NULL       | index | cov           | cov         | 20      | NULL                                    | 5058658 |   100.00 | Using index                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

The index on configuration (power,color) is not used even if I set `force index`

If I use a table instead of a subquery

```
create table tmp select distinct power,color,type from vehicle
```

then `Explain` on the 'same' query

```
select v.type,sum(c.rank)
from
  tmp v 
  join configuration c using (power,color)
group by type
```

becomes

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type |     table     | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len |         ref         |  rows   | filtered |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tmp           | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL                | 1016144 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | configuration | NULL       | ref  | veh           | veh  | 6       | tmp.power,tmp.color |       2 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

and this is 4 times faster

How can I avoid using a hard table ?

Comment: Did you add the time it took to create the temp table to the run time of the 2nd query? Because the 1st and the 2nd query are **not** the same. The 2nd query does not include the time required to create the temporary table. Btw a distinct on 3 fields has limited use for an index on 2 fields.

Comment: You are right, if I add the time taken to create the table, it's 'only' 2 times faster. Btw the table has an index on 3 fields to speed up the distinct. But the question was: why doesn't MySQL use the derived table as a reference for the join ?

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see if the datatypes match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case the optimizer thinks it is better to do it the other way around, by using the auto generated key in the derived table.

In the second case there is no key in the temp table, so the best plan is to go for tmp first.

You should be able to force the table order by using `STRAIGHT_JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.